# headless chrome browser in ruby watir not responsive after opening new tab

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, google-chrome-headless

I am using chrome headless on my linux server for web scraping.
I am getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timeout` Error

Here's my code:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser =  Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: options

browser.goto 'www.abc.com'
browser.link(text: 'hello').click!  # opens in new window
browser.windows.last.use
browser.url  # FAILING AT THIS POINT
```

Error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.105)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700
```

Comment: I don't find the link named `hello`.

Comment: you need to update your chromedriver, driver versions match browser versions now; I recommend webdrivers gem for doing this automatically.